# Filter multicast from WAN to specified vlan

Tags: linux, firewall, dd-wrt, iptables, multicast

I'm using ebtables to filter multicast IPTV from my Wireless and Wired Lan.

Right now its configured like this:

- Router ( DD WRT )
- VLAN1 (PC Network)
- VLAN2 (IPTV)

I am using this command:

```
insmod ebtables
insmod ebtable_filter
insmod ebt_pkttype
ebtables -A FORWARD -o eth1 --pkttype-type multicast -j DROP
ebtables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 --pkttype-type multicast -j DROP
ebtables -A FORWARD -o vlan1 --pkttype-type multicast -j DROP
ebtables -A OUTPUT -o vlan1 --pkttype-type multicast -j DROP
```

This works, i am not getting the multicast packets on my PC lan nor my wireless.

But i believe by doing this, i am disable all multicast traffic going and from VLAN1, hence windows network discovery doesn't see any of the other computers.

Anyway around that? i want to filter all multicast going into vlan1 from the WAN port, but enable the rest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i found it:

```
ebtables -A FORWARD -s <00:11:22:33:44:55> -o vlan1 --pkttype-type multicast -j DROP
ebtables -A OUTPUT -s <00:11:22:33:44:55> -o vlan1 --pkttype-type multicast -j DROP
```

Where 00:11:22:33:44:55 = MAC of ATT RG.